# Why design for "404 not found" page needed?

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-404

I want to know the advantage of `404 Not Found page`. Why should one create a design for that ? Why not just set `404` header and redirect it to the home page with a message something like "What do you want of the URL? Please just walk into the website".

I figured many websites have a special page for the purpose. But why ?

Regards

Comment: If I put in `http://yoursite.com/badurl`, why should it go to the `index` page?  I personally would find that confusing.  Also, I'm pretty sure some search engines penalize you for behavior like this.

Comment: The reason why you shouldn't redirect them directly to your index page is the fact that visitors are actually trying to seek "information" on that particular link they have just pressed. It's always good practice to inform your visitors in case something is not working properly, and courtesy redirecting them to the index page with consent.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think it is better that If you put a bad you url, you redirect to the index + a massage contained 'bad url'.

Comment: I could use a good massage.

Comment: @Sajad Instead of redirecting to the index, consider embedding part of your index in the 404 page. It's crucial for SEO that your server returns the 404 error status header, so make sure you work it in there somewhere.

Comment: You "could", but what happens if you don't have a `favicon.ico` and the browser requests it, instead of a 404 page you'll get redirected to `index.html` .. and if your `index.html` doesn't have a `favicon.ico`, you could go for another 404, which redirects to index .. but if you have a hard stop at the 404, you're done .. it's also good for logging and tracking your site stats; you could also setup your server to send 301 or 302 if you know the page being requested has moved .. but you wouldn't know which pages were being missed if all 404's went to index .. just a side note

Comment: Does this seem like a better fit for programmers.SE than Stack Overflow?

Comment: @trichoplax what is your mean exactly?

Comment: @trichoplax [it was already asked and answered over there](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/46193/31260)

Comment: @Sajad: Re: "If you put a bad you url, you redirect to the index + a massage contained 'bad url'": I think you may be a bit confused about how redirects work. If you redirect to the main page, then there won't be any additional message about 'bad url' (unless, of course, your main page *always* has such a message . . .).

Comment: @RobertHarvey you said If I don't use of 404 not found page, some search engines penalize me. so I want to know, If I use of this line `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` and then use of a redirect to index.php, what happens ? everything is fine ? I will not be penalize anymore ? thanks

Comment: You should return 404 not found, and leave it at that.

Comment: how `return` ? like this ? :
`header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");`
`header("Location: www.example.com");`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **404 Not Found**
>
> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.  A 404 status code does not indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or permanent; the 410 (Gone) status code is preferred over 404 if the origin server knows, presumably through some configurable means, that the condition is likely to be permanent.

[Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1), section 6.5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)

---

404 pages let users know that the page does not exist.

Many people will change the URL manually (for example, `/pictures/page/1` to `/pictures/page/2`). If you redirect the user to the front page it will be confusing to them. What they expected to happen (either go to page 2 or get a "Page not found" error) will not happen; finding themselves on the front page is not useful.

The more important thing, however, is that *users should ideally never see 404 pages*. When they actually *do* see one, it should be very clear that the page does not exist. Redirecting them does not tell them that the page does not exist; it tells them that... it is the front page, which it should not be. It is confusing.

Another issue is that search engines may find it odd that a lot of your pages get redirected to your front page. It is not exactly how the internet is supposed to work, so they may actually penalize your website because of it.

If you want your users to have a good experience on your website then your 404 pages should attempt to help them find whatever they were looking for. Some things you can show the user are:

- A search box. Google has [custom search boxes](https://cse.google.com/cse/) you can put on your website, which only search your site. If making your own is too complicated then this is a good solution.
- If you are able to do something like this, then showing the user content that *may be similar* to what they are looking for can be useful. Just make sure that it works reasonably well. For example if you cannot find anything similar then don't show random stuff -- it is not helpful.
- The newest content on the page. This is especially useful if it is a blog, news site, or some other kind of website that frequently gets new content.
- The most popular content. If the user is just browsing to pass the time then popular content may allow them to continue browsing without leaving your website.
- A link to or showing a sitemap may also be useful if the website is small enough to summarise on one page.

...and so on. Just try to think of what would be *helpful* to the user.

Comment: I agree with this sentence: *404 pages let users know that the page does not exist.* . BUT, I do not like the user walks in my directory. why should I let the user to know about my pages ? I will allow the user to just write my website name `www.example.com`. And for the rest, my website will guide him to other pages.

Comment: @Sajad But you cannot control what users do. All you can do is try to make it a good experience, also when they run into pages that do not exist.

Comment: @Sajad If you are worried about users finding pages that they should not see, then that is a security problem that you should fix. It is not something that should affect your users.

Answer (score 5):

*A good custom 404 page will help people find the information they're looking for, as well as providing other helpful content and encouraging them to explore your site further.*

Moreover if you do not make your own custom page, the server's 404 error will be displayed which would not go by the design of your website. There are also negative elements which would try to access the unauthorized pages, and keeping a check of the same will give a sense of secured website.

> What if you go in a departmental store and looking for a soap which
>   actually is out of stock, but the store keeper just make you to start
>   again from the section. Isin't the message **not available** is a
>   better option? The same goes here

Answer (score 2):

The idea of a 404 page is to tell the user that the file they were looking for wasn't found, or that the link they clicked on was broken.

Say you're running a news site and a user clicks on a link to an article on your site, but the article has been deleted. A 404 page makes it very clear to the user that the article is gone. If you just redirect them to your homepage, they might think a featured article on your page is the one they were linked to, or that they got redirected for no reason. They won't have any reason to think that what they were looking for no longer exists on your server.

So the purpose of a 404 page is to say "Hey, what you were looking for isn't here." If you want to get more fancy, you can even use a 410 error instead, which means "Hey, what you were looking for used to be here, but it's gone now."